# Something has run / ran its course

Tags: tense, present-perfect, past-participles

I'm always hearing sentences like "this x has run its course" from native English speakers. However, from my understanding, it should rather be "this x has ran its course" as it's something that has happened in the past rather than in the present. I do agree that "run", in this sentence, sounds right, but grammatically, would that be the correct choice, too? If so, can anyone tell me why this is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Has ran" is an incorrect present perfect form, because the past participle of the verb *to run* is *run*, not *ran*.  *Ran* is the simple past tense.